# Download Manager for Ubuntu that can open multiple HTTP connections

Tags: download-manager

Is there a download manager that can open multiple connections to the specified URL and download part files only to join the files later and present it as one single file?

I know about wget, but as far as i know, it opens a single connection to download. (Though can resume a interrupted download)

Is there such a download manager or a command line tool available?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, there is. Run the following commands to install:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install aria2
```

Use aria2 basically just like wget. I believe the default number of connections is 4 but you can change this by using the -x flag followed by the number of connections you would like to make. For example, to make 8 connections:

```
aria2c -x 8 http://www.example.com/example.file
```

[click here for more info](http://aria2.sourceforge.net/)

---

Also, you can use the DownThemAll extension for firefox.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) . This is precisely what I was looking for. I dunno why it didn't show on google top results when it was readily available.

Comment: Downloaded 300Mb file in 1 min, when with browser it showed me 1 hour! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

In addition to aria2, there is uGet which has a GUI as well as command line options.

Run the following commands to install uGet:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:plushuang-tw/uget-stable
sudo apt update
sudo apt install uget
```

It can also use aria2 as a backend engine if you want.

http://uGetdm.com

Comment: any idea how to setup multiple different mirrors on uGet? I mean, what separator to use as it is a simple text field.

Comment: @AquariusPower On a side note: I just checked and `uget` is now available on 18.04 without a ppa through the Universe repository. You just have to enable the Universe repository in your software settings.

Comment: @mchid uGet has been in the Ubuntu repos for over a decade :D We suggest the PPA solely because it gets updates when they are released, where as the Ubuntu Repo versions only when Ubuntu makes full updates of their system every 6 months. LTS versions of Ubuntu never get updates of uGet because it is not under our control so we have no choice in that.

Comment: @Aquarius Power you can use multiple mirrors with a comma ( , ) separator

Comment: uGet doesnt make it clear from where it is downloading. I tried with netstat, it seems to connect to a single site even after I use ',' with mirrors. If I run from terminal, it will detach and I will see no log about what is happening. But it seems to cut the file in many parts because if I stop/start it discarded a percentual. At least it finished the download properly. There was a very slow mirror that I think changed its name (redirect), so I couldnt see it on netstat, so I removed one by one manually until fixed.